# Lotusscript Excel VBA Right Syntax (SUBSTITUTE)

Tags: excel, vba, lotusscript

I have been trying to use Excel formula in LotusScript. I could not find the correct syntax of it. See below the formula.

What I want to do is just a convert Column Number to Column Letter in Excel via Lotusscript. This formula should return E4 but I get an error "OLE: Automation object error"

```
Dim cFormula as String
cFormula = "=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(4;5;4);1;0)" 
xlsheet.Cells(20, 12).formula = cFormula
```

Comment: Please show us your complete code. Is xlsheeet correctly initialized? Where is your ExcelApplication- Object, etc. etc. OLE Automation object usually means that the code could not correctly remote control excel / open file

Comment: The excel is working fine. If i remove this lines IT works correctly. When i add It does not work. I think I need the correct syntax of this formula in LotusScript. My Excel Export agent has more than 800 lines. Do you really want me to send it?

Comment: Inho This has nothing to do with the formula, there is something else wrong. You don‘t need to post 800 lines, just the relevant ones... as it is an ole error, show the definition and initialization of all relevant variables (Excel application, excel file, excel sheet)... does this error happen with a simple formula like „=A1“ es well?

Comment: In your 800 lines, do you have any other lines that modify a cell value or a cell formula, and which do not throw an error?